# Xcode does not recognize new test functions

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

I've just started writing unit tests and I've encountered an issue. So far I've dug through different blogs on google and stackoverflow but I haven't been able to resolve this.

Every time I write a function to be tested the run button (shaped like a diamond) does not appear. The only run buttons that do show up are the default functions created by Xcode when you create a new unit test target.

Here's an example of the issues.

[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkZwA.png)

Could it be a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

test needs to be on the front of the function signature. ie: `test"functionName"()`

Comment: This is right. `newTestExample` is not a legal test method name. Change it to `testExampleNew` or similar.

Comment: Shoutout to Apple for making this needlessly weird.